PostgreSQL | DB latency issue for hash partitioned tables
We have few occurrences of database queries taking longer duration than expected. This is happening for a table which is of hash partitioned (16 partitions). Each partition is of 330GB each.
1.) There is a primary key (partition key) on the table (bigint). 2.) We have another index (non-unique and NULL) on a column which was introduced much later in the table logic (~3 years back). Currently 51% of records are NULL in this column.
At times, during non-business hours, we see that a spike on the query fetch based on the second index. The prepare statement is similar to below.
select  ,  from table where <2ndindexcolumn>=$1 limit 55;
The above statement is taking ~10seconds or more to execute at only specific intervals and also we see statement timeouts as app configured for 10sec. This is part of transaction and is executed at a very high rate at database. Postgres version (16.4)
When we dynamically execute the same parameters on database, that fetch is within milliseconds.
What could be the cause of this strange behaviour?
We are inclined to parameter sniffing, but the issue is across all the threads in multiple pods at the same time.
Also, We don't see any locks and plenty of I/O and other resources at database.
Expecting a theory on why the query perform badly only a few seconds in the whole execution timeframe

How the cardinality of your 2nd column for the rest 50% of data? does it have skew with certain values? You probably getting occasional sequential scan if you having skew. Since 50 % of it are NULL ,including NULLS in index won't do any favour , i think it's better to have filtered index with 2ndindexcolumn is not null

"We are inclined to parameter sniffing" - what did you do to validate that hypothesis?

We have mostly 10(50% data) same records present in and max 30k records(1% data),rest all are single records. we are also  suspecting parameter sniffing and also noticed no sequence scan from stats.
